# Probably memory leakage on ffmpeg when doing a multiple trims and concat filter. What's the workaround?

Tags: ffmpeg

Example:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "input1.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=3624.005:end=3630.005,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vidFinal];" -map [vidFinal] output.mp4
```

ffmpeg just reads through the entire video file just to cut 6 seconds out of the video. Is there a way to avoid this with -filter_complex? Because I have multiple trims of multiple large video files and reading through a couple of 6 hour video files when needing only 6 seconds parts is too much.

Comment: You can just do `ffmpeg.exe -ss 3624.005 -to 3630.005 -i "input1.mp4" -an output.mp4`

Comment: Yeah but I would've liked to trim and concat all my clips (100+) in one go. Right now I render 100+ clips with the approach you mentioned and concat them afterwards.

Comment: It will be very inefficient, in terms of CPU/RAM to trim 100 files in one command.

Comment: Yeah I realized that. Had about 11GB of used memory. I now trim the parts individually. Thanks for the help anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an [known issue](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/10550).

This is the way suggested there:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -i input.ts -filter_complex "
[0:2]trim=start=200:end=220,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];
[1:2]trim=start=400:end=440,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];
[v1][v2]concat[v3];
[0:2]trim=start=1440:end=1500,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v4];
[v3][v4]concat[vout]
" -map [vout] -c:v libx264 output.mkv
```

After some testing, this problem is still identified on version 6.1.1, even if I nerfed the parallelization as above.

Either 5.1.4 or latest branch (2024-3-20) will do the job. At least no memory leak.